# Is it possible to programmatically add a softkey shortcut to an application in Symbian

Tags: mobile, symbian, shortcut, s60

Is it possible for a Symbian S60 application to automatically add itself to one of the softkeys. The best would be if it could be done at installation time but if there is some API that can be used to add a shortcut the first time the application runs that would also be ok in our case.

Does Symbian has some best practices around this. I can guess that some users may be upset  if some application overwrites his settings if he/she has configured the softkey shortcuts to refer some other application,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/ScShortcuts_Engine_Wrapper_API) is what you are looking for. I will not comment on Symbian best practices about that, but would like to say that were an application to override one of my defined shortcuts, I would be annoyed. If it is absolutely necessary, I for one would display a prompt during installation and request whether the user knowing that the application once installed will override one shortcut softkey would want to continue with the installation or not. In fact, when and if you choose to get your application Symbian signed, you may or may not be required to put such a confirmation box during installation.